Upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 failed, emergency mode
I wanted to upgrade my Ubuntu to 24.04, but the upgrade failed providing a series of errors. I see all my data there. Is there a way to go back to normal before I try to update again?
Results of journalctl -xb :
Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/CC95-4815
Dependency failed for /boot/efi
Dependency failed for local file system
Failed to get new runlevel, utmp update skipped

consider switching to wq_unbound

Timed out waiting for device:

Results of lsblk :

